# Can I direct MX records to one server and domain name to another server

Tags: email, dns, web, mx-record

I'm having some trouble understanding domain and mx records.

If I direct the domain name from the register to where I am hosting a site. And on the Register I direct the MX records to another server that takes care of the email will that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what MX records are for.

Let's say, your domain is whatever.net.
You create A records for domains that you want to point to your website, i.e. www.whatever.net, whatever.net. They will point to the **IP** of your web server.

Then you set an MX record that points to a **domain**, typically something like mail.whatever.net.
You must then set up an A record for mail.whatever.net to point to the IP of your email server.

Note that your mail domain does not have to be a subdomain of your domain. It can also be something completely different. For instance many small businesses set their MX to mail.google.com and sign up with google to handle all of their emails.

Comment: I don't know why this got a down vote as it really is useful to understand. Thanks MrTweek for clarifying this for me